# What is the proper word for increase in pain?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, appropriate

What is the proper word for increase in pain?

I want to let someone know if the pain increases then there would be consequences.

> However, for the worst case scenario if the pain .....

Thought of using

1. increases
2. rises
3. shoots up

etc.

Not able to figure out what would be appropriate here.

**EDIT:**

I am not just looking for which word is appropriate out of the three options I suggested. I am looking for any appropriate word.

I am looking for **more** appropriate/suitable word here, if any.

Comment: The most common would be **gets (any) worse**.

Comment: Increases wild be best, rises is good but you'd need something like "the *level* of pain rises" and then shoots up would also fit but implies a quick and large increase.

Comment: You didn't explain why _increase_ is not suitable.

Comment: @alwayslearning given the explanation, if that helps.

Comment: @deadrat I think your comment gives me my answer. Think to add as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi I couldn't turn down such a gracious offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Intensifies* might work. Doctors use a 0-10 self-reported pain scale, in which 0 is no pain and 1 is barely noticeable up to 9, which is excruciating enough that suicide is preferable and 10 is pain so bad that immediate unconsciousness ensues. So in a clinical setting, you might say to a patient.

> You report tolerable pain now, which is a 3 on the pain scale. If your pain **intensifies** to 5 or more, you must seek help immediately.

I wouldn't use *shoot up* because of the collision with *shooting pain*, a different type of pain from say, an ache. I wouldn't use *rise* because of the collision with the use of the word for fever.

Comment: The driveby downvoter strikes again, a curse on this site. Your discourtesy leaves me with no idea how to fix a wrong answer and may mislead the OP into thinking a right answer is lacking.

Comment: Downvoting relieves the pain of his miserable existence.

Comment: @ab2 Thanks for the laugh; it relieved this (very minor) pain in my (not at all) miserable existence. Just for the record and just to make people think I'm not taking it personally and myself too seriously, I also leave this note for driveby downvoters on answers not my own.